# How to pass props in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and I am finding it difficult to pass props from one component to another.
This is the first component

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
      // show:true
    };
  }
  counter = () => {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="">
        <div>{this.state.count}</div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the second

```
export default class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="">
        <App />
        <button onClick={this.counter}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How do I make the counter count by passing props in the apps component

Comment: You should make Button as a child component of your App, not the other way around, then pass counter function down to Button as a props

Answer (score 1):

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
      // show:true
    };
  }
  counter = () => {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="">
        <div>{this.state.count}</div>
        <Button counter={this.counter} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="">
        <button onClick={this.props.counter}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```